# Tengo un template en html y cada vez que lo uso se enlista uno tras otro

Tags: javascript, html

Sere mas especifico, estoy haciendo una pokedex en html y casi la tengo lista, hice un template para mostrar los atibutos del pokemon, pero cada que le doy a buscar los templates se enlistan y yo quiero que solo aparezca uno ¿Que puedo hacer? disculpe si se ve mal estructurado soy nuevo en eso de la programacion web.

Aqui busque pikachu y todo normal.

[image]

Pero al buscar otro, el template se añade abajo del primero y pikachu sigue apareciendo, si busco mas solo se van enlistando, yo solo quiero que aparezca uno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el codigo donde se crea el tmplate.

```
const llenarData = (pokemon) => {
    console.log(pokemon)

    const flex = document.querySelector('#conten')
    const template = document.querySelector('#template-card').content
    const clone = template.cloneNode(true)
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()

    clone.querySelector('#img-poke').setAttribute('src', `img/${pokemon.id}.gif`)
    clone.querySelector('#nombre').innerHTML = `${pokemon.nombre}`
    clone.querySelector('#IDpoke').innerHTML = `#${pokemon.id}`
    clone.querySelector('#tipo').innerHTML = `${pokemon.tipo}`
    clone.querySelector('#peso').innerHTML = `${pokemon.peso} kg`
    clone.querySelector('#altura').innerHTML = `${pokemon.altura} m`
    clone.querySelector('#ataque').innerHTML = `${pokemon.ataque}`
    clone.querySelector('#defensa').innerHTML = `${pokemon.defensa}`
    clone.querySelector('#especial').innerHTML = `${pokemon.especial}`


    fragment.appendChild(clone)
    flex.appendChild(fragment)
}
```

Y intente con `flex.innerHTML = ""` pero solo me da un error que dice que el contenido en mi div es null y no se puede leer.

Comment: Muestra, como se ven el navegador para poder ayudarte

Comment: Listo ya añadi algunas imagenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes de limpiar el html con una función

```js
const llenarData = (pokemon) => {
    console.log(pokemon)
   
   /*  llama la funcion limpiar html ante de llenar la data
        y ante de llenar la data limpiara el html de cualquier
        personaje anterior
    */
    limpiarHTML ()

    const flex = document.querySelector('#conten')
    const template = document.querySelector('#template-card').content
    const clone = template.cloneNode(true)
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()

    clone.querySelector('#img-poke').setAttribute('src', `img/${pokemon.id}.gif`)
    clone.querySelector('#nombre').innerHTML = `${pokemon.nombre}`
    clone.querySelector('#IDpoke').innerHTML = `#${pokemon.id}`
    clone.querySelector('#tipo').innerHTML = `${pokemon.tipo}`
    clone.querySelector('#peso').innerHTML = `${pokemon.peso} kg`
    clone.querySelector('#altura').innerHTML = `${pokemon.altura} m`
    clone.querySelector('#ataque').innerHTML = `${pokemon.ataque}`
    clone.querySelector('#defensa').innerHTML = `${pokemon.defensa}`
    clone.querySelector('#especial').innerHTML = `${pokemon.especial}`


    fragment.appendChild(clone)
    flex.appendChild(fragment)
}









function limpiarHTML () {
  flex.innerHTML = ''; // la variable flex es donde se agrega el template del personaje
}
```